# How to remove a rows in a dataframe that contain non-float/integer variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a rather large dataframe, I am looking to preprocess the inputs by standardizing them using the sklearn preprocessing module.

However, this error shows up:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

How do I go about removing ANY row containing a non-float/integer type of value from my pandas DataFrame?

Here's the type of dataframe I have.

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0.02,  0.32], [1 04,  2 64], [2 06,  4 96]], columns=['A', 'B'])

Out[2]: 
   A  B
0  0.02  0.32
1  1 04  2 64
2  2 06  4 96
```

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, a], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

#eliminate the space as a decimal separator and use a dot.

Out[2]: 
   A  B
0  0.02  0.32
1  1.04  2.64
2  2.06  4.96
```

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(your_numpy_array, errors='coerce')`?

Comment: pd.to_numeric(unscaled_inputs_all, errors='coerce') gives off an error "TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series"

Comment: Is your numpy array not one dimensional? Can we see some sample data?

Comment: It has several rows and columns

Comment: Do you have a numpy array or a pandas dataframe? Either way, please provide some sample data and the full traceback of the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you for the source on how to improve question-making

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stack` with `str.replace`

```
new_df = df.stack().astype(str).str.replace(' ', '.').astype(float).unstack()

      A     B
0  0.02  0.32
1  1.04  2.64
2  2.06  4.96

print(new_df.dtypes)

A    float64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this often to make numerical dataset from the data

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
display(df.select_dtypes(include=numerics).columns)
df_numerics = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)
df_numerics.head()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I used it on a pandas DataFrame. Afterwards, I converted it back to a numpy array.

Comment: Afterall it did not work perfectly as it also eliminated entire columns. I only wanted it to eliminate the rows in which the invalid non-numeric values showed up